# How to always know up-to-date cookie expiration time in Analytics.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, universal-analytics

My app exchanges data with Google Analytics and it needs to always know the time when the GA cookie will expire.

I'm setting cookie expiration time while creating the tracker:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28  // Cookie expiration time
});
```

But according to [analytics.js docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains), this value can change if a request is sent to GA servers:

> Every time a hit / request is sent to Google Analytics servers, the
>   cookie expiration time is updated to be the current time plus the
>   value in the cookieExpires time (in seconds) into the future

**Is there a way to have a single event handler for all events in analytics.js? Or is there another solution for always knowing the time when the GA cookie will expire?**

Answer (score 1):

You can not read expiration time of the existing cookie.

So you can solve it by setting an additional cookie (storing expiration time) for the same period that the original cookie every time you send a hit:

```
function ga_expiration() {
    var period = new Date();
    period.setTime(new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*28); // time in milliseconds
    document.cookie = 'ga_expiration=' + period.toUTCString() + '; expires=' + period.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
}
```